# Unable to change RDS instance class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to upgrade the instance class of our database to increase capacity, but whenever I try I get an error

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the ModifyDBInstance operation: Invalid max storage size for engine name mysql and storage type gp2: 1001
```

I've tried using the RDS console, and the CLI but get the same error.

I have absolutely no clue what this error means though. For storage, we have the following configuration:

[image: storage config]

When I first setup the database, the storage was much smaller. We increased the storage to 1000GB to get more IOPs but everything was valid then. How can it be invalid now?

Comment: What exactly are you changing? Just the instance type? What is it currently and what are you changing it to?

Comment: @jordanm yeah just the instance type. Trying to upgrade from db.m5.xlarge to db.m5.2xlarge. Trying this command, not changing anything else - aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier our-db --db-instance-class db.m5.2xlarge --apply-immediately

Comment: I would try first disabling the storage auto scaling. Scaling from 1000GB to 1001GB isn't that useful to begin with.

Comment: heh very valid point. Never really thought about that, I'd even just set that to 1001 more or less to stop it doing it. Disabled it and it's let me change the instance type! If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I was facing exactly the same problem today, and the advice to disable storage autoscaling also got me out of the bind. My questions for @jordanm now would be: "Why does that solve the problem, and how did you know?" I have done a lot of combing through the RDS docs since then and have not found anything that addresses this particular gotcha. Also my web searches haven't turned up anything else corroborating this (very good and accurate) advice, which I find pretty mystifying.

Comment: @Hephaestus I've been working on AWS extensively for years and I think this was just a good guess based on the error message. My comment was a long time ago, so it's difficult to remember.

Comment: have you checked this ? https://serverfault.com/questions/918141/aws-eb-and-rds-invalid-storage-size-for-engine-name-mysql-and-storage-type-gp2

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated storage of 1000, and with autoscaling enabled, you need to have at least 10% larger storage for the Maximum storage threshold but you only have 1001.

Generelly speaking, when you increase the allocated storage, it must be by at least 10 percent so it does not make sence to have autoscaling enabled in your case, if you still want autoscaling then change the max storage to be at least 1100.

Comment: I wasn't trying to increase the storage at all, just the instance type. The error relating to storage was the misleading part since I wasn't actually trying to change this. Disabling autoscaling resolved the issue as suggested by jordanm

Answer (score 0):

Or bring maximum storage threshold down to 1000.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html

Comment: I wasn't trying to change the storage at all, just the instance type. The error relating to storage was the misleading part since I wasn't actually trying to change this. Disabling autoscaling resolved the issue as suggested by jordanm

Comment: I know, I've been there too. It's an interesting situation where a previously working config all the sudden fails because more storage has been automatically provisioned. Disabling autoscaling or tweaking the storage parameters are the solutions I've found to work.

Comment: Yeah that's what worked here as well. Just disabling autoscaling which we didn't need anyway, and it worked just fine